# What are the vm-driver and driver falgs in Minikube?

Tags: macos, docker, proxy, minikube, hyperkit

I am using Minikube in macOS.

I found this in `~/.minikube/config/config.json`:

```
{
    "driver": "docker",
    "vm-driver": "hyperkit"
}
```

What are they, and what is the difference?
Does `Minikube` use `Hyperkit` as a virtual machine and run in it? If so, why do it needs the driver settings?

Also, I see a lot of `minikube start` with:

```
--docker-env http_proxy=url
--docker-env https_proxy=url
--docker-env no_proxy=url
```

there are the proxy settings in the docker settings (that is, the proxy settings in the dashboard in docker desktop for mac), are these parameters not needed if the driver is set to docker?

And does the proxy in docker refer to the network environment in `hyperkit`? Because I think `docker pull` and `push` are done in docker daemon, which is running on `hyperkit`.

Answer (score 3):

I also was confused about the difference betwenn `--vm-driver` and `--driver`, and I found that `--vm-driver` is the old name and it is deprecated, and today `--driver` is the correct option

Answer (score 2):

Any environment set using `--docker-env` will go to the docker daemon service. And `vm-driver` is which hypervisor to use. If you run `minikube start --help` you will find below information

> --driver='': Driver is one of: virtualbox, parallels, vmwarefusion, hyperkit, vmware, docker, podman

So you can use any of above drivers to start your k8s cluster.